# necesito crear un archivo .htaccess para redireccionar urls amigables

Tags: .htaccess, pretty-urls

Tengo un sitio en mi hosting pero tengo un error al momento de darle click a mis productos, como verán  pueden ingresar a mi web.

Quiero ir a algún producto de mi página, pero el htaccess no me envía la vista:

```
http://imnovesa.com/lineas_de_productos/iluminacion/iluminacion_convencional
```

Es decir necesito crear un url amigable para esa ruta.

Comment: esa url por definicion ya estaria en forma amigable, que tan amigable la quieres?

Comment: te comento que esa es la url , te invito a ingresar al sitio para que veas ...

Comment: alli podras ver que cuando le damos click a un producto, mi web se queda en blanco.

Comment: la web del link está en blanco para mi

Comment: ¿Qué intentaste? ¿Cuál es la URL a la que se debe acceder, y cuál es la URL a la que tiene que reescribir? En el estado en el que está tu pregunta actualmente, es imposible responderte. Te recomiendo leer acerca del tema, intentar algo y, si en ese momento te surgen problemas, ahí hacer una pregunta en el sitio.

Comment: ingresa a la web sin el ´´www´´ solo imnovesa.com .. e intenta verificar un producto.

Answer (score 0):

suponiendo que estes trabajando con APACHE Y PHP podrias agregar la siguiente regla a tu archivo `.htaccess` para obtener:

```
http://imnovesa.com/lineas_de_productos/iluminacion/iluminacion_convencional
```

En resumen deberias agregar la siguiente linea a tu archivo `.htaccess`

```
RewriteRule ^lineas_de_productos/(\w+)/(\w+)/?$ lineas_de_productos.php?cat=$1&subcat=$2
```

Comment: me puedes apoyar ? skype o algo?